# How can I get a notification when the user logs out from facebook.com?

Tags: logout, facebook-php-sdk

The user is logged in to my site using the latest PHP SDK.
If the user clicks the facebook logout URL that appears in my site, he logs out from facebook and is redirected back to my site where I can do some cleanups.

However, if while in session (in my site and in facebook) the user goes to www.facebook.com and logs out from there, my site is clueless about it. I need to be notified about this in my site so I can do cleanups.

The only solution I can think of is to call from every page in my site to getLoginStatusUrl(), but this seems to be an overkill. Isn't there a way to ask facebook to call some URL in my site when the user logs out from facebook itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use js to subscribe to the auth.logout event as per the facebook example:

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>',
      cookie: true,
      xfbml: true,
      oauth: true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
    });
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Comment: For me this does not fire when the user logs out of Facebook. Only when they log out using connect. (i.e. FB.logout with the JS API).